# Minimum number of moves required to get a permutation of a int of array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, int, sequence, permutation

You have a sequence of `d[0] , d[1], d[2] , d[3] ,..,d[n]`. In each move you are allowed to increase any d[i] by 1 or 2 or 5 i:0 to n .What is the minimum number of moves required to transform the sequence to permutation of `[1,2,3,..,n] if it's possible else return -1. 1<=n<=1000`

My approach is sort the given array in ascending array than count it by adding 1 or 2 or 5 . But it fails in many cases .`Some of my classmates  did this in exam using this method  but they read question wrong so read question carefully .`

e.g. [1,1,3,2,1] than answer is 4 since We can get [1,2,5,4,3 ] by adding 0,1,2,2,2 respectively  so answer is 4 .

[1,2,3,4,1] => [1,1,2,3,4] we will get 4 using sorting method [0,1,1,1,1] but answer is 2 since we can add [2+2] in 1 to get [1,2,3,4,5] .

similarly

[1,2,3,1] =>[1,1,2,3] to [1,2,3,4] required 3 transformation but answer is 2 since by adding [1+2] to 1 we can get [1,2,3,4].

Another method can be used as but `i don't have any proof for correctness` .

```
Algorithm
    input "n" is number of element , array "a" which contains input element 
    initialize cnt = 0 ;
    initialize boolarray[n] ={0};
    1. for i=0...n  boolarray[a[i]]=1;
    2. put all  element in sorted order whose boolarray[a[i]]=0 for i=0...n
    3. Now make boolarray[a[i]]=1; for i=0..n and count
      how many additions are required  .
    4. return count ;
```

According to me this question will be result in  0 or more  always since any number can be produced using 1 , 2 and 5 except this case when any d[i] i=0..n  is greater than number of Inputs .

```
How to solve this correctly ?
```

Any answer and suggestions are welcome .

Comment: Is the solutions always possible? The requirement for that would be d[i] <= i for i = 1 ... n

Comment: If not then return -1 .

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: Show us your approach

Comment: Can you show some of those cases where your approach failed? And also tell us what the correct value is for those cases, and how you know that.

Comment: @Soana It's not my Homework , this question was asked in online Coding for intern .

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  I used sorting and one for loop it passes only 3 cases .

Comment: Can you show the actual cases?

Comment: How large can n be? In other words what is your desired complexity?

Comment: @Corei13 n is between 1 and 1000 .

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Which case do you want ? case which passes or failed .

Comment: just post some cases so we can test

Comment: Is it possible to add `2` multiple times? Let's say you have `[1,1,2,3,4]`, is `[0,4,0,0,0]` as two steps a valid answer?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind read question carefully that is done by many people in exam "any d[i]" .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be converted in [weighted  bipartite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs) problem :-

> 1. first part p1 of graph are the current array numbers as nodes.
> 2. second part p2 of graph are numbers 1 to n.
> 3. There is edge between node of p1 to node p2 if we can add 1,2,5 to it to make node in p2.
> 4. weighted bipartite matching can be solved using the hungarian algorithm

**Edit :-**

If you are evaluating minimum number of move then you can use [unweighted bipartite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs) . You can use **hopcroft-karp algorithm** which runs in `O(n^1.5)` in your case as number of edges `E = O(n)` in the graph.

Comment: But the complexity is too high o(n^3) . It can be solved using sort .Read question again and check there is any meaning of "any d[i]"

Comment: @user3805652 if you check in the same link there is an algorithm which uses fibonacci heaps to do it in O(n^2*logn). What is the max n ?

Comment: @user3805652 sorry i misread your question and thought you need to minimize the total sum of the extra added values but you have to minimize the total number of moves. Check my edit

Comment: @user3805652 yes i realized it later

Answer (score 0):

Create an array `count` which contains the count of how often we have a specific number in our base array

```
input    1 1 3 2 1
count    3 1 1 0 0
```

now walk over this array and calculate the steps

```
sum = 0

for i: 1..n
    while count[i] > 1                   // as long as we have spare numbers

        missing = -1                     // find the biggest empty spot which is bigger than the number at i
        for x: n..i+1                    // look for the biggest missing
            if count[x] > 0 continue     // this one is not missing
            missing = x
            break;

        if missing == -1 return -1       // no empty spot found

        sum += calcCost(i, missing)
        count[i]--
        count[missing]++

 return sum
```

calcCost must be greedy

Comment: It might be advantageous to pick not the biggest missing number in all cases. For instance, if you're looking for how to generate 10, and you got both 5 and 7 in the available numbers, you might have to pick 5 as this would need 1 move to get to 10, whereas the 7 requires 2, but this depends on what you can then use 7 for later.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i runs from left to right, whereas missing runs from right to left, so i'm taking the biggest missing and the smallest spare number, which results in that five is promoted to 10 and 7 to 8 or 9 in your example